# can I use str_replace in all xml nodes with php?

Tags: php, xml, str-replace, xmlnode

I think the problem is with my logic and I am probably going about this the wrong way. What I want is to

- open an xml document with php
- get elements by Tag name
- then for each node that has child nodes
- replace every letter `a` with `ა` every `b` with `ბ` and so on.

here is the code I have so for but it doesn't work.

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("temp/word/document.xml");
    $nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("w:t");

        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            while( $node->hasChildNodes() ) {
                $node = $node->childNodes->item(0);
            }
            $node->nodeValue = str_replace("a","ა",$node->nodeValue);
            $node->nodeValue = str_replace("b","ბ",$node->nodeValue);
            $node->nodeValue = str_replace("g","გ",$node->nodeValue);
            $node->nodeValue = str_replace("d","დ",$node->nodeValue);

            // More replacements for each letter in the alphabet.
    }
```

I thought it might be because of the multiple `str_replace()` calls but it doesn't work with even just one. Am I going about this the wrong way or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

The `$node` variable gets overwritten on each iteration, so only the last `$node` will get modified (if ever). You need to do the replacement inside the loop and then use `saveXML()` method to return the modified XML markup.

Your code (with some improvements):

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load('temp/word/document.xml');

foreach ($xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("w:t") as $node) {
    while($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        $node = $node->childNodes->item(0);
        $search = array('a', 'b', 'g', 'd');
        $replace = array('ა', 'ბ', 'გ', 'დ');
        $node->nodeValue = str_replace($search, $replace, $node->nodeValue);
    }
}

echo $xmlDoc->saveXML();
```

Comment: ahh this looks good so will this still apply the replace to every w:t tag

Comment: @gcoulby: Yes; why don't you try it and see?

Comment: i had to leave the house. i will be back in an hour and i will update you. and mark as correct once it works which im sure it will.

Comment: The search and replace array works great if I use it with
   'code'$xmlContents = file_get_contents($word_dir);
   unlink($word_dir);
   file_put_contents($word_dir, $xmlContents);'code'
the problem with this method is it changes every character in the XML file effectively breaking the file... hence the need for nodes.
However, your code is not working with this method. The program goes through the notions and even overwrites the file but all the letters remain untouched.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42270/discussion-between-amal-murali-and-gcoulby)